# how to control pose of an armature real time in blender?

Tags: python, blender

I'm creating a devise to identify hand movements and display on 3d hand model in blender.For that I used flex sensors and accelarometer to measure finger/hand movements.By using pyserial the sensor values are imported to bender as many variables.

I'm new to blender and python.I have created a hand model and need to run it using python script.I have added always sensor and python controller. I need to change the pose of the bone(actually euler angles) in real time using those sensor values(In blender game engine).

I have tried many codes and non of them does not work.Can someone please send me a blender file(.blend) for  single bone runs real time in using input values(eg variable x).It could be a great help for me..

Comment: This question may be better suited for [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There has been some work on using a kinect with blender, you might find some help in that work.

From python you can manipulate an armatures bones with -

```
myrigbones = bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones
myrigbones['chest'].rotation_euler = Euler((12.0, 0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```